# Are there any advantages to using all principal components vs. all original variables?

Tags: machine-learning, pca

Are there ever any advantages to using all principal components vs. all original variables for any analysis?

For the sake of this question, let's assume that it's either one or the other, so there isn't any dimension reduction.

Comment: Are you limiting to the case of at least as many observations as there are variables? That is necessary to avoid dimension reduction.

Comment: Some statistical or machine learning methods just need or assume that the data are uncorrated features.

Comment: @ReneBt Yeah, I am limiting it to that case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Principal components have a diagonal correlation matrix. That is, the components are uncorrelated, so "no confounding factors." This reduces standard errors of regression coefficients and precludes worrying about artifacts due to endogeneity. Unfortunately, PCA shifts the pressure to interpretation of the components. What are they, exactly, in some meaningful, domain-specific notion? This is generally fairly hard to  elucidate, but if you can find an *a priori* reason to believe that the components should be mixed as they are, then that counts as a genuine *aha* moment -- a real discovery of interpretation.

Incidentally, we should also use Hermite polynomials $\{1$, $x$, $x^2-1$, $x^3-3x, \dots \}$ instead of the usual $\{1$, $x$, $x^2$, $x^3, \dots\}$ for polynomial regression for the same reason: Hermite polynomials are orthogonal to each other in the same way that principal components are orthogonal to each other.  We *should* but we don't, because, rather like principal components, they are too hard to explain to marketing.

Answer (score 0):

## Basic aspects of PCA relevant to question

PCA is effectively decomposing you original observations into a series of simultaneous equations, ranked in terms of how much they contribute to the overall data set. They are also created such that the pattern of the variable contributions are orthogonal between the PCs.

## Information post PCA vs original variables

If you number of observations = number of variables then using all your PCs captures exactly the same information as the original variables. In this select case the solution is exactly determined.

If your number of observations exceeds the number of variables you have an over-determined solution.  This means that you have more equations than variables. What happens in this case is that variance is explained until the number of pcs = the number of variables. Any variance remaining after that is not captured by the PCA.

What is this unexplained variance? First note that it will be the smallest contributors to the overall variance of the dataset. Whether the unexplained variance is useful or not is an entirely different question - amongst many other options it may be

- describing random noise
- describing observation artifacts and biases
- describing subtle non-linear effects within the data generating process
- describing real effects that are much weaker than those captured in the top ranked PCs.

This means that if you use an over-determined PCA some information is lost compared to the original variables, which may or may not be a good thing depending on the nature of the information lost.

## Conclusion

> Are there ever any advantages to using all principal components vs.
> all original variables for any analysis?

PCA is advantageous to

1. eliminate noise and irrelevant artifacts from your
   data if that is what the excluded information represents
2. restructure your variables so that they are
   orthogonal for input into further analysis
3. data exploration to understand the inherent interaction of your variables within your dataset